# Why does Chrome not show the prompt with Allow or Disallow permission to microphone and webcam?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, webrtc

I have built simple video chat with SimpleWebRTC, and when I start WebRTC on the Ubuntu Chrome 34 shows me the prompt with Allow or Disallow permission to microphone and webcam. I click allow and can start conversation if even I don't have webcam.

But when I start WebRTC on Windows 7 Chrome 33 doesn't show any prompt. But I can see cross webcam icon in address line. And when I try to allow Chrome to use microphone and webcam It's reloading. So what I need to do for showing the prompt as in Linux?

My code is:

```
    webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
        // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video
        localVideoEl: 'publishers',
        // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
        remoteVideosEl: 'subscribers',
        // immediately ask for camera access
        autoRequestMedia: true
    });
    webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () {
        webrtc.joinRoom(sessionId);
    });
```

Also I can reproduce it with this [demo](http://apprtc.appspot.com). I got next error message in that demo app:

> Failed to get access to local media. Error name was
>   PermissionDeniedError. Continuing without sending a stream.

Comment: I tested it and it asks me the permission. Maybe you checked an option which remember your choice for the URL. Try the same in Incognito mode.

Comment: I have just tried in Incognito mode, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Yacine Rezgui, do you have webcam plugged/built in?

Comment: I just tried it and it works. I open it with another tab and I got that 3D effect when someone joins the room.

Comment: @Dmitro Dumb question here: Do you have a microphone and cam on that PC you are working on?

Comment: it by default tries to grab video AND audio. If you do not have a camera, it will fail each time unless you tell it only audio.

Comment: I tried set autoRequestMedia: false but after this it doesn't work even audio.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? Chrome stops asking on HTTPS once you accept or block once. Do you get a prompt on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpsq6u5v) using HTTP? If so, then @philidem 's answer is likely the right one.

Comment: I have this issue with hangouts.google.com and meet.google.com routinely, no other sites so far. I have explicitly set those domains to allow audio and video but it doesn't work or popup to ask for permission. I have tried clearing all site data in the Chrome dev tools thinking maybe it is a service worker or a deeper cache. I can't yet tell if it is a Chrome bug or an application level bug.

Answer (score 4):

There's a new security feature on Chrome 59:

Temporarily stop permission requests after 3 dismissals
Security

Temporarily stop an origin from requesting a permission following the third dismissal of a permission prompt. The stop will be lifted after some amount of time has passed (initially 1 week), after which the origin may request the permission again. A further dismissal will apply the temporary stop again.

For web developers who are testing features, the block can also be removed by changing the permission's setting in the lock icon's page info dialog, or by clearing your browsing data.

Source: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6443143280984064

Comment: This can be unblocked by go to Settings -> Site Settings -> Camera -> Blocked List -> Allow

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may have blocked the domain from ever asking for media access. You can remove this exception from within Chrome Settings.

Open Chrome **Settings** and then navigate to:

**Settings** `>` **Privacy** (within advanced settings) `>` Click **Content settings..** `>` Click **Manage exceptions...**

Make sure your domain does not have **Block** value for Audio/Video. You can remove the entry for the blocked domain if it exists.

Comment: it looks like it, but on my chrome on ubuntu it has no exceptions yet the popup still does not appear

Comment: I have the same thing in Windows 10 Chrome (`Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)`), popup does not appear, have uninstalled and re-installed chrome, checked site settings to 'ask' etc).

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same SimpleWebRTC setup and it wasn't working in both Chrome and Firefox and I clearly had no approvals/dismissals made before (which could be a reason why browsers don't ask) *but I was accessing my local dev environment without https* and most modern browsers block HTTP-only transfer of image and audio recorded by the device. Just prepending an 'https' did the trick for me.